# How can I write a PHP script to zip and download an Assets subfolder?

Tags: plugin-development, craft3, plugins, php

I've searched everywhere but can't seem to get a straight answer.  I want to write a php script to zip and download an entire subfolder in my assets directory.  The subfolders are named based on a variable.  Where do I write this php code?  Must I write a custom plugin for something so simple?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you'd need to [write a plugin](https://nystudio107.com/blog/so-you-wanna-make-a-craft-3-plugin) to do this... or you could [write a module](https://nystudio107.com/blog/enhancing-a-craft-cms-3-website-with-a-custom-module). There are some plugins that may already do what you want tho: [Squeeze](https://plugins.craftcms.com/squeeze) / [Compress](https://plugins.craftcms.com/compress)

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I'm already using Squeeze, it only seems to zip files, not a folder.

Comment: @JJefferyDev you can combine multiple files in one download so you should be able to retrieve a complete folder with it.